# Hourly frequency count with Python

Tags: python, time, pandas

I have this Hourly csv datas sorted like this day by day for hundreds days:

`2011.05.16,00:00,1.40893

2011.05.16,01:00,1.40760

2011.05.16,02:00,1.40750

2011.05.16,03:00,1.40649`

**I want to make a count of how many times per hour the daily maximum value has been set, so if on 00:00 i had the maximum value of 2011.05.16 day i add 1 to 00:00 and so on.** To do this i used a loop to count hours like indexes in this way:

```
def graph():    
Date, Time,  High = np.genfromtxt(myPath, delimiter=",",
                                  unpack = True,  converters={0:date_converter})                                                                           
numList = [""] * 24
index=0
hour=0    
count = [0] * 24

for eachHour in Time:        
    numList[hour] += str(High[index])        
    index += 1
    hour +=1        

    if hour == 24:           
        higher = (numList.index(max(numList)))
        count[higher] += 1            
        hour = 0            
        numList = [""] * 24
```

The problem is that in my datas often there's a gap with some hours missing, but the loop can't recognize it and continue putting values in the next hour index. I've searched everywhere, but i'm new to programming and this is my first "complex" work so i need more specific answers to my case for understand how it works. **So how do you make an hourly frequency count like explained?** 
The final result should be like:

```
00:00 n time max of the day   
01:00 n time max of the day   
02:00 n time max of the day  
etc
```

Comment: You've added `pandas` as a tag, but you don't seem to be using it.  Would a `pandas`-based solution be acceptable?

Comment: Of course any solution would be acceptable.

Comment: By "highest value of the day set", do you mean "the highest value *ever* on that day, i.e. the daily maximum", or do you mean "a new maximum was set"?

Comment: WoW! Well sorry guys i didn't expected so much partecipation here :) i meant the daily maximum, not the highest value ever. e.g every time the highest value of the day is at 15:00, add 1 count at 15:00. Now i need sometime to check all this answers, thanks to all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First read in the csv:

```
In [11]: df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', sep=',', header=None, parse_dates=[[0, 1]])

In [12]: df.columns = ['date', 'val']

In [13]: df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
                         val
date                        
2011-05-16 00:00:00  1.40893
2011-05-16 01:00:00  1.40760
2011-05-16 02:00:00  1.40750
2011-05-16 03:00:00  1.40649
```

Use resample to get each days maximum:

```
In [15]: day_max = df.resample('D', how='max')
```

Check whether each value is the day max:

```
In [16]: df['is_day_max'] = day_max.lookup(df.index.normalize(), len(df) * ['val']) == df.val

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
                         val is_day_max
date                                   
2011-05-16 00:00:00  1.40893       True
2011-05-16 01:00:00  1.40760      False
2011-05-16 02:00:00  1.40750      False
2011-05-16 03:00:00  1.40649      False
```

And then sum these over each hour:

```
In [18]: df.groupby(df.index.time)['is_day_max'].sum()
Out[18]: 
00:00:00    1
01:00:00    0
02:00:00    0
03:00:00    0
Name: is_day_max, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hmmph.  On second reading, I think you're right and the OP is looking for the daily maximum, not merely the setting of a new max. :-/

Comment: @DSm although cummax kindof makes more sense (is going to have more Trues)

Comment: @AndyHayden I think you last step (the resample by hour) is not what is he asks. And by the way, if not all hours available, this will generate errors ('Cannot convert NA to integer')

Comment: @joris Ah, of course, it NaNs rather than 0s if empty, thanks!

Comment: Your way seems to be working, but i don't know how to group the results to show me just a list of the 24 hours and the count (i want to plot it using matplotlib). Could you help me? (btw seems like you're using ipython, i'm using Idle)

Comment: The last step in my answer does this (`df.groupby(df.index.time)['daily_max'].sum()`)

Comment: @AndyHayden I edited your answer, as it was not correct (as far as I understand). I hope this is OK.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with pandas: Supposing you have a dataframe with the date is index, you can first add a column to indicate the maximum value per day, and then groupby by hour and sum the occurrences:

```
In [32]: df['daily_max'] = df.groupby(df.index.date).transform(lambda x: x==x.max())
In [33]: df
Out[33]: 
                       value daily_max
date_time                             
2011-05-16 00:00:00  1.40893      True
2011-05-16 01:00:00  1.40760     False
2011-05-16 02:00:00  1.40750     False
2011-05-16 03:00:00  1.40649     False
2011-05-17 02:00:00  1.40893      True
2011-05-17 03:00:00  1.40760     False
2011-05-17 04:00:00  1.40750     False
2011-05-17 05:00:00  1.40649     False
2011-05-18 02:00:00  1.40893      True
2011-05-18 03:00:00  1.40760     False
2011-05-18 04:00:00  1.40750     False
2011-05-18 05:00:00  1.40649     False

In [34]: df.groupby(df.index.time)['daily_max'].sum()
Out[34]: 
00:00:00    1
01:00:00    0
02:00:00    2
03:00:00    0
04:00:00    0
05:00:00    0
Name: daily_max, dtype: float64
```

---

With older pandas version, this will give the same result as above (assuming your `df` has a DatetimeIndex):

```
df['date'] = [t.date() for t in df.index.to_pydatetime()]
df['time'] = [t.time() for t in df.index.to_pydatetime()]
df['daily_max'] = df.groupby('date')['value'].transform(lambda x: x==x.max())
df.groupby('time')['daily_max'].sum()
```

---

The dataframe I used in this example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

s="""2011.05.16,00:00,1.40893
2011.05.16,01:00,1.40760
2011.05.16,02:00,1.40750
2011.05.16,03:00,1.40649
2011.05.17,02:00,1.40893
2011.05.17,03:00,1.40760
2011.05.17,04:00,1.40750
2011.05.17,05:00,1.40649
2011.05.18,02:00,1.40893
2011.05.18,03:00,1.40760
2011.05.18,04:00,1.40750
2011.05.18,05:00,1.40649"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=None, names=['date', 'time', 'value'], parse_dates=[['date', 'time']])
df = df.set_index('date_time')
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it give me this error:                       df['daily_max'] = df.groupby(df.index.date).transform(lambda x: x==x.max())
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: That would mean that your index is not a DatetimeIndex. Did you read the data as I showed in the answer? Otherwise, you could also try `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` to convert the string to a datetime.

Comment: Or, it could also mean that you have an older pandas version where the `date` attribute is not yet available for a DatetimeIndex. I added a version that can be used with older pandas versions, although I recommend to try to update.

Comment: Lol combining your answer and the other it works! thank u very much for help!

Comment: Did the first part of my answer not work? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: I don't know how to explain since i'm a beginner, but on canopy gaves me (NotImplementedError: file structure not yet supported) after making your correction (to convert a string to a datetime). But i can see now on python 3.3 Idle it works! It gives me a list like this:                                                     00:00:00 38.0 NaN False. 01:00:00 20.0 NaN False etc.                                              So i can see also your answer works. The other was a little easier for me to use, but without this (df.groupby(df.index.time)['daily_max'].sum()) it wouldnt work. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to calculate, but this is how I would approach doing calculations of the values in your data set

```
from time import strptime,strftime

time_format="%H:%M"
date_format="%Y.%m.%d"

def date_values(flo):
    for line in flo:
        try:
            date_str, time_str, value = line.split(',')
            date = strptime(date_str,"%Y.%m.%d")
            time = strptime(time_str,"%H:%M")
            value = float(value)
            yield (date, time, value)
        except ValueError:
            pass

def day_values(flo):
    days = {}
    for date,time,value in date_values(flo):
        try:
            days[date].append(value)
        except KeyError:
            days[date] = [ value ]

    return days

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import stdin

    for day,values in day_values(stdin).items():
        print("{0}: {1} (max of {2})".format(
              strftime(date_format, day),
              values, 
              max(values)))
```

The date_values function will return a generator that iterates over valid lines of your data input.  The day_values function uses the generator to construct a dictionary in which the keys are the dates and the values is an array of values for that date.  From your description I'm not sure how the time comes into play, if you can clarify, or provide a larger data set with an example of the result you would like to see, I can expand on this.

If I name that file`freq_count.py` and assuming your data set in a file named `data`, I get

```
$ python freq_count.py < data
2011.05.16: [1.40893, 1.4076, 1.4075, 1.40649] (max of 1.40893)
```

To count the frequency of the max value:

```
def count_freq(values):
    return len( [ v for v in values if v == max(values) ] )
```

that uses a list comprehension to generate a list containing all values that are the max in the `values` input, then take the length of the resulting list.