# Daily frequency count with pandas

Tags: python, count, pandas

[As in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819702/hourly-frequency-count-with-python) that i already asked, i'm trying this time to make the same count but on a daily basis. So i would like this time to **make a count of how many times the lower value of a week is set on monday, how many times on tuesday, etc, and the get the count aggregated for the 7 days of the week** for a list of days and values like this:

2013.01.01,00:00,1.31802

2013.01.02,00:00,1.32038

2013.01.03,00:00,1.31859

2013.01.04,00:00,1.30508

etc.

I'm currently using Pandas for this, and the piece of code that i used to make an hourly count was:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myPath, sep=',', header=None, parse_dates=[[0, 1]])
df.columns = ["date","value"]
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
day_min = df.resample('D', how='min')
df['is_day_min'] = day_min.lookup(df.index.normalize(), len(df) * ['value'])==df.value
df.is_day_min.resample('H', np.sum).fillna(0).astype(int)    
df.groupby(df.index.time)["is_day_max"].sum().to_csv("C:\\2013frequency_min.csv")
```

But when it comes to analyze daily datas if i change resample to "W" in day_min (4th line), and to "D" in 6th line it gives this error: KeyError: Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00', tz=None)

Can anyone help? I'm sure this is simple but pandas docs are not helping me.
Even if anyone have a solution not using pandas show it to me. If it works it's ok.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use TimeGrouper, by week (and see whether the value is equal to the week's min) and then resample by day:

```
In [11]: week = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W'))

In [12]: is_week_min = week['value'].apply(lambda x: x == x.min()).astype(int)  # possibly the astype is not needed in 0.13

In [13]: is_week_min.resample('D', how='sum')  # count occurences in the day which are week min
Out[13]: 
2013-01-01    0
2013-01-02    0
2013-01-03    0
2013-01-04    1
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

If you wanted this as columns as days of each week, you could do the groupby within the apply:

```
In [14]: week['value'].apply(lambda x: ((x == x.min()).astype(int).groupby(x.index.dayofweek)).sum()).unstack(1)
Out[14]: 
            1  2  3  4
2013-01-06  0  0  0  1
```

*Note: the index is the WeekEnd.*

and with the pastebin link you provide:

```
In [21]: df = pd.read_csv('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SuyWZLj5', header=None, parse_dates=[[0, 1]])
         df.columns = ['date', 'value']
         df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

In [22]: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).value.apply(lambda x: ((x == x.min()).astype(int).groupby(x.index.dayofweek)).sum()).unstack(1)
Out[22]: 
             0  1  2  3   4
2013-01-06 NaN  0  0  0   1
2013-01-13   0  0  0  1   0
2013-01-20   0  0  0  1   0
2013-01-27   1  0  0  0   0
2013-02-03   0  1  0  0   0
2013-02-10   0  0  0  0   1
2013-02-17   0  0  0  0   1
2013-02-24   0  0  0  0   1
2013-03-03   0  0  1  0 NaN
```

Comment: Yes. It works. But what if i need just the count displayed on an index from 1 to 7 representing the days of the week (grouping in a single week the results of all the dataframe)?

Comment: @user3142367 Maybe df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).value.apply(lambda x: ((x == x.min()).astype(int).groupby(x.index.day)).sum()).unstack(1)

Comment: You're very nice for giving time for my question. But in this way you suggested it gives me the number of the day in the month. What i need is like "we had 4 times the lowest value of the week on monday, so we add 4 to monday (or day 1)" and so on for tuesday, wednesday etc.

Comment: Looking better i saw that your code gives me as lowest days of the week simply all the sundays. Wich is strange, since in my datas there is only from monday to friday datas! Maybe you can give a look to my file at http://pastebin.com/SuyWZLj5 if you want to make a clue.

Comment: @user3142367 That's not what I see with the csv you provide (I get dayoftheweek between 0 and 4...

Comment: If you look on the calendar you can see 2013-01-06 is sunday and so on for the others...and if you check the file the days you get are not even listed there, as it contains only monday to friday. So if not listed it can't be the lowest day of the week, and all the days should be 4 but it doesn't seems so...

Comment: @user3142367 the 6th is the last day of the week (the Sunday), that is 0 is Monday, 1 is Tuesday, etc.

Comment: @user3142367 columns 5 and 6 do not appear (as there are no Saturdays or Sundays in the dataset), the 6 would correspond to the last day of the week (and is used as the index).

Comment: Added a little correction in the end to visualize results better.